# Why does the following bash string removal not work for me?

Tags: bash

```
s=abcdefg
echo ${s%c}
```

I expect the output to be `ab`, but `abcdefg` is printed.

I'm on bash 4.30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${s%c}` removes the *shortest suffix matching the pattern*. Your pattern is "c".

It looks like you want `${s%c*}`:

```
$ s=abcdefg; echo ${s%c*}
ab
```

See more in [the bash manual's section on Shell Parameter Expansion (3.5.3)](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Answer (score 1):

The notation that you are using only removes when the pattern (after the %) matches at the end of the string.

```
s=abcdefg
echo ${s%c}
```

result: abcdefg

```
echo ${s%efg}
```

result: abcd

To get the behavior you were expected add a *

```
echo ${s%c*}
```

result: ab